# How can I ask jsoncpp to encode unicode strings?

Tags: c++, linux, jsoncpp

I'm using the following code to test jsoncpp

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Json::Value root;
    root["test"] = "中文测试123";

    Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
    cout << styledWriter.write(root) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is like this

```
{
   "test" : "中文测试123"
}
```

I'm wondering if jsoncpp can escape those unicode to `\\uXXXX`?

I've tried both FastWriter and StyledWriter, non of them works

Comment: Try `u8"中文测试123";` to make sure the string is stored as UTF8. When you say *"it doesn't work"* that could mean lots of things. Can you print `cout << u8"中文测试123"`?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani error: ‘u8’ was not declared in this scope?

Comment: @daisy Your compiler is old

Comment: Why would you? JSON is a *human readable* format.

Answer (score 2):

### It depends on which version you are using.

---

### using jsoncpp 1.8.3

```
{
   "test" : "中文测试123"
}
```

### using jsoncpp 1.8.4

> released on Dec 21, 2017
> related commit: Serialize UTF-8 string with Unicode escapes ([#687](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/pull/687))

```
{
   "test" : "\u4e2d\u6587\u6d4b\u8bd5123"
}
```

### using jsoncpp 1.9.2

> released on Nov 14, 2019
> related commit: Added emitUTF8 setting. ([#1045](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/pull/1045))

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <iostream>

void print_json(const Json::Value& value, bool emitUTF8) {
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
    builder.settings_["emitUTF8"] = emitUTF8;
    std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
    writer->write(value, &std::cout);
}

int main() {
    Json::Value root;
    root["test"] = "中文测试123";

    print_json(root, true);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    print_json(root, false);
}

/*
output:
{
    "test" : "中文测试123"
}
{
    "test" : "\u4e2d\u6587\u6d4b\u8bd5123"
}
*/
```